# Multiple counts on the same SQL Server 2012 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a better way to count row of an id based on different criteria?

For instance I have a table that with columns:

```
id, state, city
```

My query:

```
select 
    ID, city, state, UScount, statecount, citycount
from    
    (select count(*) USCount, ID  
     from table 
     group by ID) UScount
inner join 
    (select count(*) stateCount, ID  
     from table 
     group by ID, state) statecount on UScount.ID = Statecount.ID
inner join 
    (select count(*) cityCount, ID  
     from table 
     group by ID, city) citycount on UScount.ID = citycount.ID
```

I am just trying to clean this up because in reality I have about 20 different counts and it does not look very nice

Comment: `select sum(case when field = 'foo' then 1 else 0) as foo_count`

Comment: @MarcB not really the group by change

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for window functions?

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over () as cnt,
       count(*) over (partition by state) as cnt_state,
       count(*) over (partition by state, city) as cnt_state_city
from table t;
```

I am not sure if `id` should be part of the `partition by` or not.

Comment: i was going to post that!

Comment: Blast - beaten by 30 seconds!